# Web API 2.0 endpoint with Forms Authentication that does not reset the sliding timeout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

Is it possible to have a specific web api 2.0 endpoint not refresh the sliding scale in forms authentication?

We have a legacy web forms app that also has an api project inside it, using forms authentication to `[Authorize]`.

There is a timer in the main SPA web page that is calling a web api endpoint to measure the connection speed and show that in an animation at the top of the page. However it is keeping the user logged in even when she is not active.

I'd like that method to not register as user activity, so the user gets logged out after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Is it possible within the same web app (without creating a new web app just for this purpose)?